# What is the most secure way to connect to a WCF Service from monodroid?

Tags: c#, wcf, security, xamarin.android, wcf-security

I have a WCF Service which I need to call from a monodroid app. I want to prevent users from using a tool like fiddler to read the data. I tried using TLS with server- and clientcertificates but it seems that monodroid doesn't support clientcertificates. Is there another option I could try to secure the service?

Edit: To clarify the question: I'm looking for a possibility to encrypt the communication between the app and the service to prevent man in the middle attacks like using fiddler or another proxy. The best thing I found so far is using a basicHttpBinding with transport security and a server certificate but this doesn't work against man in the middle attacks.

Answer (score 0):

You can secure the WCF service with username and password, the below url's provides how to create wcf service with username and password feature

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/96028/WCF-Service-with-custom-username-password-authenti

http://www.felinesoft.com/blog/index.php/2014/02/securing-a-wcf-service-with-username-and-password-using-message-security-and-the-channel-factory-pattern/

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this doesn't work. They use wsHttpBinding with message security in these examples but with monodroid I can't use that. The best thing I could do was to try it with basicHttpBinding and transport security but I could still read the communication data with fiddler.

Comment: https://github.com/khoanguyen/WcfEx/wiki/Basic-Authentication-for-REST-service---WebHttpBinding                                                                           check this out

Comment: you can use webHttpBinding and username authentication                                                 if you use webHttpBinding, all the clients can be able to consume your service

Comment: This isn't helping me, either. I'm looking for a possibility to encrypt the communication with the service to prevent man in the middle attacks like using fiddler or another proxy. Maybe I didn't express myself clear enough, I'm going to edit the question for clarity.